# What happens to the data in an existing DynamoDB table when you change the billing mode from PROVISIONED to PAY_PER_REQUEST?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This question is to make sure my understanding is right.

We have millions of records in an existing production DynamoDB table. Right now the billing mode is set to PROVISIONED with auto scaling enabled. I am planning to change the billing mode to PAY_PER_REQUEST.

I made the changes in the cloud formation template, tested it in a lower level environment and the performance results were fantastic. I am planning to promote this change to production. Just wanted to check when the switch is complete, are there any chances of me losing my data? I believe the answer is no, I will not lose my data after changing the billing mode from provisioned to pay_per_request because I see the following in the AWS documentation -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand

“Table Behavior while Switching Read/Write Capacity Mode

When you switch a table from provisioned capacity mode to on-demand capacity mode, DynamoDB makes several changes to the structure of your table and partitions. This process can take several minutes. During the switching period, your table delivers throughput that is consistent with the previously provisioned write capacity unit and read capacity unit amounts. When switching from on-demand capacity mode back to provisioned capacity mode, your table delivers throughput consistent with the previous peak reached when the table was set to on-demand capacity mode.”

Can someone who has done this before let me know whether my understanding is right? I want to be careful if switching the billing mode has some detrimental effect (like restore my table as we have point in time recovery enabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't lose any data when you change your billing mode.

If you'd like to take the extra precaution, you could perform a [backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BackupRestore.html) of your tables in case any issues come up.

Quick note, that you're *only* able to switch billing modes once per 24 hour period based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand)

> You can switch between read/write capacity modes once every 24 hours

Comment: That is wonderful. Thanks for confirming that the data will not be lost. Yes, I have enabled point in time recovery so the backups are in place. You are right about the 24 hours period, I saw that in the documentation. Thanks again for confirming.

Comment: We did this yesterday and everything went smooth. No loss of data.